# D3, removing points to refresh with new ones

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I am trying to set a function so I can refresh my d3 setup by (hopefully) just calling this function. I have a d3 map with topojson set up and am plotting points on it - the desired effect is to have the user change the data on the map.

So inside my d3 script I have the part where I plot the points separated out into a function like so -

```
 function plotPoints(data){
 svg.selectAll(".pin").exit().remove();

 svg.selectAll(".pin")
.data(data.earthquakes)
.enter().append("circle", ".pin")
.attr("r",function(d){
    return d.magnitude/2;
})
.on('mouseover', tip.show)
.on('mouseout', tip.hide)
.attr("transform", function(d) {
 return "translate(" + projection([
  d.lon,
  d.lat
 ]) + ")"

});

}
```

then at the very bottom i initiate it with some sample data  like -

```
plotPoints(places);
```

This works fine - however what I am tyring to do up top there with

```
thesvg.selectAll(".pin").exit().remove();
```

is remove all the first set of points before adding the second. I can't seem to get this detail correct and am not sure why. When I run the function as is (without the remove part) it just adds the new points ontop of the old ones. Would appreciate very much some help on this matter. Bonus points if there is a way to animate the points in and out with a stagger. I don't know if this helps but it's within an angular application. Thanks very much for reading.

Edit: I was able to solve it by using

```
 svg.selectAll("circle").remove();
```

However, I am still trying to figure out how to animate in/out with a stagger.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're not understanding how the enter, update, exit selection patterns work.  Take a look at http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/

In short, you're calling `exit()`, but you haven't bound any data in that call, so the `exit()` selection will be empty.

I'd suggest that you want to change `svg.selectAll(".pin").exit().remove();` to `svg.selectAll(".pin").remove();`

Note that I don't have `exit()` in the changed line.  The line will now select all DOM elements with the `pin` class and remove them from the DOM.